ParserError: Source Not Found Despite Correct Path
I'm encountering a ParserError when trying to compile my Solidity contract. The error indicates that the specified path is not found, even though I believe the paths are correct.
Error message:ParserError: Source "node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol" not found: No import callback.
--> contracts/HashedTimeLockERC20.sol:4:1:
|
4 | import '../../../../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol';
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ParserError: Source "node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol" not found: No import callback.
--> contracts/HashedTimeLockERC20.sol:5:1:
|
5 | import '../../../../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol';
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error HH600: Compilation failed
Here's the relevant part of my Solidity file (contracts/HashedTimeLockERC20.sol):
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.23;
import '../../../../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol';
import '../../../../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol';
I have verified that the specified paths are correct and that the files exist at the given locations. Additionally, I have the @openzeppelin/contracts package installed in my node_modules.
I have tried the following solutions without success:
Using both relative and package import paths.
Clearing the Hardhat cache with npx hardhat clean.
Ensuring the node_modules directory is present and correctly structured.
Reinstalling all dependencies with npm install.

What error are you getting when importing directly like import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";?

it compiled succefully. Although I still have red undermarks for that imports

You might have to disable any ESLint extension and reload the VS code.
